# Screen recorder android without notifications

Tags: java, android

I have an app, where I need to record screen. I used media recorder api, but i found out that it uses a buffer from gpu, so i cant capture part of the screen and hide notifications. It seems to me that it is possible to do this using ffmpeg, but I could not find information

Comment: what exactly is your question ?

Comment: i need help finding a way to record only my app without notifications and statusbar